# Fortran with Sparse BLAS not flushing memory

Tags: fortran, sparse-matrix, blas, intel-mkl

I have a subroutine that builds sparse matrices, and I need to call it several times. However, it seems that if I call this subroutine a lot of times (and/or if the sparse matrices are very large), memory consumption in my machine starts to accumulate. Given that my matrices are quite large, repeated calls to the subroutine make the program crash eventually. It seems that Fortran is not flushing/freeing the allocated memory after completing each subroutine call.

I'm building these sparse matrices using the Sparse BLAS library that comes with oneAPI MKL, and using the `ifort` compiler.

Below, I have an example where I build a small matrix with Sparse BLAS many times. Iterations do not change anything, but as I understand this, memory consumption shouldn't start increasing after each iteration. However, it does. If I were using regular (dense) matrices in this loop rather than using Sparse BLAS, memory consumption doesn't increase at all. For example, if I comment the last line in the loop where I call `mkl_sparse_d_create_csr`, the program doesn't crash.

```
program test

use iso_c_binding
use mkl_spblas
implicit none

integer,parameter     :: n = 5
integer               :: iter,i,j,stat
real                  :: csr_ref(n,n)
integer               :: count_row,count_nnz
integer               :: jcol(1),irow(n+1)
real(C_DOUBLE)        :: vals(1)
type(SPARSE_MATRIX_T) :: csr

! Dummy matrix
csr_ref = 0.0
csr_ref(1,1) = 1.0

! Iterating many times
do iter = 1,1000000000
    
    ! Builing CSR matrix
    irow = 1
    count_nnz = 0
    do i = 1,n
        count_row = 0
        do j = 1,n
            if (abs(csr_ref(i,j)) > 1e-4) then
                count_row = count_row + 1
                count_nnz = count_nnz + 1
                vals(count_nnz) = csr_ref(i,j)
                jcol(count_nnz) = j
            end if
        end do
        irow(1+i) = count_row + irow(i)
    end do

    ! Create sparse matrix
    stat = mkl_sparse_d_create_csr(csr, SPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ONE, n, n, irow(1:n), irow(2:n+1), jcol, vals)

end do

end program test
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like some memory leak. You do not use any pointers, so the faukt can be in the library.

Comment: I don't know how these MKL routines work, but usually when there is some "creation" routine with a descriptor (`csr`), there is a "destroy" routine that has to be called to release any allocated memory during the creation phase.

Comment: Can you provide us with a link to the documentation for the routine? A quick google is not that helpful. But I agree with @PierU - to me it looks like you are creating billions of separate objects, one for each call, and as the memory for them is not handled by Fortran I don't see why you can expect it to be automagically deallocated.

Comment: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-fortran/2024-0/mkl-sparse-destroy.html

Comment: The function called here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-fortran/2024-0/mkl-sparse-create-csr.html  --- I note that the docs here don't mention needing to call destroy later, which I would argue is a defect in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are required to call `mkl_sparse_destroy` to recover the memory allocated by `mkl_sparse_?_create_csr`.  This is explicitly stated in the online documentation for `mkl_sparse_destroy` but unfortunately not in the online documentation for `mkl_sparse_?_create_csr`.

References:

- Intel MKL docs for `mkl_sparse_?_create_csr`: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-fortran/2024-0/mkl-sparse-create-csr.html
- Intel MKL docs for `mkl_sparse_destroy`: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-fortran/2024-0/mkl-sparse-destroy.html